# How do I set a Tkinter frame's background to expand with the frame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In my root window for my Tkinter application I have two main frames. One on the left, which will be used as a toolbar, and one on the right, which will be used to view images. I want the frame on the left to stay the same width so I set it's column weight to 0 and the frame on the right's column weight to 1.

The problem I'm struggling with is that the right frame will not expand with the window, but the frame will center align so I assume it is attempting to expand. I believe the problem is that the frame is shrinking to its contents (the sub-frames and widgets). How can I prevent this?

Here is the simplified version of my code (just take a look at the images, there's a bit more going on here):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.configure(background='black')
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.configure(background='red')
frame2.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

[Screenshot of before I expand the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfeso.png)

[Screenshot of after I expand the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsnuT.png)

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Try adding `sticky="news"` to `.grid(...)`. Also you might need `root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` as well

Comment: The color of the frame will always fill the frame. They aren't distinct things. If it appears the color isn't expanding, that just means the frame itself isn't expanding.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @TheLizzard, adding the argument

```
sticky='nesw' # North East South West
```

to

```
.grid(...)
```

seemed to nicely expand my frame, 'sticking' it to the edges.